# How to use a JS var in Jquery (mp3 playlist)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an album feature to the existing jplayer.

This is the working static code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


            new jPlayerPlaylist({
                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
            }, [
                {title:"01 - Standing (Still)", mp3:"music/Ongesorteerd/01 - Standing (Still).mp3"},
                {title:"02 - Standing (Motion)", mp3:"music/Ongesorteerd/02 - Standing (Motion).mp3"},  // tracklist here
            ]);

            $("#jplayer_inspector_1").jPlayerInspector({jPlayer:$("#jquery_jplayer_1")});

        });
```

Now I want to fill the playlist by using a variable.
I managed to create a valid variable which I can alert is JS and checks out to be correct.

My question is how can I replace the static playlist whit my (JS)variable?

This is what I tried:

```
function player(album, tracklist){

            //alert(album+" ## "+tracklist);

            var array = tracklist.split("+");
            var track_count = array.length;
            var tracks = "";
            var i=0;

            while(i < track_count)
            {
                tracks = tracks+'{title:"'+array[i]+'", mp3:"music/'+album+'/'+array[i]+'.mp3"},';
                i++;
            }


            new jPlayerPlaylist({
                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
            }, [
                $(tracks)  // this is the variable I'm talking about
            ]);

            $("#jplayer_inspector_1").jPlayerInspector({jPlayer:$("#jquery_jplayer_1")});
        }
```

I'll get the following error:

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {title:"01 - Standing (Still)", mp3:"music/Ongesorteerd/01 - Standing (Still).mp3"},{title:"02 - Standing (Motion)", mp3:"music/Ongesorteerd/02 - Standing (Motion).mp3"},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original code, the following represents a javascript array literal:

```
[
   {title:"01 - Standing (Still)", mp3:"music/Ongesorteerd/01 - Standing (Still).mp3"},
   {title:"02 - Standing (Motion)", mp3:"music/Ongesorteerd/02 - Standing (Motion).mp3"},  // tracklist here
]
```

In your code you are building a string, rather than an array literal. Try something like this

```
var tracks = [];
while(i < track_count)
{
   tracks.push({
      title: array[i], 
      mp3: "music/'+album+'/'+array[i]+'.mp3"
   });
   i++;
}

new jPlayerPlaylist({
      jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
      cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
}, tracks );
```

Comment: This is a great step in the right direction, thanks! But there is still one issue, the playlist shows up correctly but the songs do not play.

I'll get the following error:

TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$("#jplayer_inspector_1").jPlayerInspector({jPlayer:$("#jquery_jplayer_1")})')

I will play with it some more.

Comment: I found it, the mp3 url was not correct. All the quotes need to be the same: mp3: "music/"+album+"/"+array[i]+".mp3". It works great now, Thanks again!